# Serial tool list_ports_windows cannot detect serial port

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port

I'm trying to list the serial ports in my Windows based PC.

This is my port list: (COM3 & COM8)

[image]

**Code:**

```
if sys.platform.startswith("win32"):
    from serial.tools.list_ports_windows import *

elif sys.platform.startswith("linux"):
    from serial.tools.list_ports import *

else:
    raise ImportError("Sorry: no implementation for your platform {} available".format(sys.platform))

.........Class definition and other methods..................

def GetList(self, verbose=True):
        """
            gets the list of all available ports
        """

        results = []

        hits = 0

        iterator = sorted(comports())

        # list them
        for port, desc, hwid in iterator:
            comPort = port
            if verbose:
                descValue = desc
                hwidValue = hwid
                results.append({'comPort': comPort, 'descValue': descValue, 'hwidValue': hwidValue})
            else:
                results.append({'comPort': comPort})
            hits += 1

        results.append({"available": "{} ports found".format(hits)})

        return results
```

**Output:**

```
[{'hwidValue': 'PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_1E3D&SUBSYS_21F317AA&REV_04', 'descValue': 'Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM3)', 'comPort': 'COM3'}, {'available': '1 ports found'}]
```

**Question:**

Why can't i see all the ports in my PC is there a problem in my code?

as you can see in the picture i have 2 ports COM3 and COM8.

**Does `list_ports_windows` has limitations for Virtual com ports?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you that using the WMI (python wmi module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/)

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
wql = "Select * From Win32_SerialPort"
for item in c.query(wql):
    print item
```

<strike>The result is the same, only hardware serial ports are listed. So I suppose the same happens with your implementation for the same reason, eg. you can get ONLY the hardware ports.</strike>

**Edit**: according to Kobi K this does list virtual ports.

You can check however for all the virtual ports in the registry: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM\**

Comment: Actually your code is listing all the ports! I don't why the `list_ports_windows ` is ignoring the virtual ports, if no one will be able to explain that i'll use your code and accept your answer.

Comment: Interesting, I remember that this code failed to list virtual ports back in some point in time. Maybe this changed during windows updates,  I can't test this since I haven no virtual port on my machine at the moment.

Comment: I'll try to investigate more if i'll find something i'll update this answer. Worst case i'll just move to Linux :)...